# Grouping using Sliding Window and Transpose

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

A dataframe (df) contain two columns as below:

```
A    B
46   0
45   1
46   1
51   1
47   1
46   1
45   0
48   0
47   0
45   1
49   1
```

I need to design a sliding window kind of grouping for each three rows, such that:

1) Take first three rows, transpose column(A) and append third entry of column(B), so we get a row of four columns as below:

```
46 45 46 1
```

2) Then move down by one row (i.e. start from row 2 in original df), repeat step-1 so we get the second output as below.

```
45 46 51 1
```

3) At each iteration, we get the successive output as below:

```
46 51 47 1
51 47 46 1
47 46 45 0
...
```

In summary, the desired output is -

```
46 45 46 1
45 46 51 1
46 51 47 1
51 47 46 1
47 46 45 0
...
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post with desired output for clarity... rollback if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `numpy`'s `stride_tricks` -

```
as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

w = 3  # window size

i = as_strided(df.A.values, (len(df) - (w - 1), w), df.A.strides * 2)
j = df[['B']].values[(w - 1):]

np.hstack((i, j))

array([[46, 45, 46,  1],
       [45, 46, 51,  1],
       [46, 51, 47,  1],
       [51, 47, 46,  1],
       [47, 46, 45,  0],
       [46, 45, 48,  0],
       [45, 48, 47,  0],
       [48, 47, 45,  1],
       [47, 45, 49,  1]])
```

Comment: @jezrael You misunderstood the question... OP wants a rolling transpose

Comment: @jezrael So, what I think OP was trying to do was provide a step by step iterative explanation of how the output is formed. I guess that was what confused you. After putting each iteration's output together, the problem becomes a bit more clear

Comment: Thanks both of you..  Infact I wanted the answer posted by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, using a sliding window.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the zip approach

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan You're welcome. I doubt anything can top this in terms of speed. I'd be _very_ surprised to see a solution that could.

Comment: @coldspeed, Can you please add to the solution, how can I get an extra (fifth ) column which contain the value in column(B) at the fourth row (one row ahead of the window's length. Appreciate your kind response. Thank you, [Asif]

Comment: Okay, I did through this way, I hope its not bad.                                                    k = df[['B']].values[(w):]
data = np.hstack((i[:-1], j[:-1], k))

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what as_strided is and how to use it? I read the documentation and I'm intimidated by the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a numpy and python approach

```
def get_list(x,m) : return list(zip(*(x[i:] for i in range(m))))

A = np.array(get_list(df['A'],3))
B = np.array(get_list(df['B'],3))[:,-1]
new = np.append(A,B[:,None],1)

array([[46, 45, 46,  1],
       [45, 46, 51,  1],
       [46, 51, 47,  1],
       [51, 47, 46,  1],
       [47, 46, 45,  0],
       [46, 45, 48,  0],
       [45, 48, 47,  0],
       [48, 47, 45,  1],
       [47, 45, 49,  1]])
```

As @coldspeed said conversions demand time and are bit computaionally expensive so we can use a simple list comprehension i.e

```
A = get_list(df['A'],3)
B = get_list(df['B'],3)
new = [(*i,j[-1]) for i,j in zip(A,B)]

[(46, 45, 46, 1),
 (45, 46, 51, 1),
 (46, 51, 47, 1),
 (51, 47, 46, 1),
 (47, 46, 45, 0),
 (46, 45, 48, 0),
 (45, 48, 47, 0),
 (48, 47, 45, 1),
 (47, 45, 49, 1)]
```

Comment: Though keep in mind... if you are using an approach with `np.append`, it is _always_ faster to append to a python list and convert one time later. Conversion is expensive, you need to allocate memory.